# Nullpointer when back to activity

Tags: android, arrays, fragment, json

I will try to explain the problem.

1. I have an activity that makes a request to a server.

   ```
      @Override 
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        doServerRequest();
      }
   ```
2. On request success, I use the returned JSONArray to create mulitple tabs and populate a recycle view on each one. It works perfectly.
3. In my adapter class, I pass an specific index to the fragment, in
   order to render the recycleView. The JSONArray is passed through the
   TabsAdapter constructor.

   ```
       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
          BloqueioFragment tab = null;
          try {
             JSONObject profissionais = profissionais.getJSONObject(position);
             BloqueioFragment tab = new BloqueioFragment(profissionais);
          } 
          catch (JSONException e) {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }
          return tab;
       }
   ```
4. The fragment use this JSONObject on the onActivityCreated method, where the recycleView is populate and the recycleAdapter is initialized.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
       try {
           JSONArray profissionais = franquiasProfissionais.getJSONArray("profissionais");
           initListaBloqueio(profissionais);
           initBloqueioAdapter();
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           System.out.println("ERROR INFO: " + e.getMessage());
       }
   }
   ```
5. I add a listener on each created recycleView to open another
   activity.

   ```
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
           ...
           startActivity(intent);
       }
   ```

   5. I open this new activity clicking/touching on any item from any recycle view.
   6. Now, when I touch the back button to return to the previous activity, it returns:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at BloqueioFragment.onActivityCreated.

The fragment onActivityCreated method is called before the request success, it tries to create tabs and populate the recycleView with an empty object.

I want that everything get reload again when get back to the list.

What I have to do to solve this problem?

That's the json, I cut it because it's huge. With this one would be generated two tabs from the index "name", like this first one "Castro (CS)"

```
[{
    "nome": "Castro (CS)",
    "profissionais": [{
        "id": "3544",
        "nome": "ALINE BECHER SALES",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "2113.39",
        "dias_trabalhados": "15",
        "proc_30_dias": "297",
        "indice_aceitacao": "91.30",
        "media_produtividade": "19.8",
        "estimativa_conclusao": 59
    }, {
        "id": "12735",
        "nome": "CAMILE DE OLIVEIRA CHASTALO",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": true,
        "ticket_medio": "1318.15",
        "dias_trabalhados": "20",
        "proc_30_dias": "466",
        "indice_aceitacao": "87.36",
        "media_produtividade": "23.3",
        "estimativa_conclusao": 50
    }, {
        "id": "5155",
        "nome": "CARLOS ROBERTO NOVAKOWSKI FILHO",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "1769.04",
        "dias_trabalhados": "15",
        "proc_30_dias": "154",
        "indice_aceitacao": "88.57",
        "media_produtividade": "10.3",
        "estimativa_conclusao": 113
    }, {
        "id": "3581",
        "nome": "CYNTIA ERDMAN SALATA",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "1658.22",
        "dias_trabalhados": "16",
        "proc_30_dias": "171",
        "indice_aceitacao": "78.43",
        "media_produtividade": "10.7",
        "estimativa_conclusao": 85
    }, {
        "id": "10090",
        "nome": "DOUGLAS PORTO FERREIRA",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "1161.17",
        "dias_trabalhados": "8",
        "proc_30_dias": "64",
        "indice_aceitacao": "81.25",
        "media_produtividade": "8.0",
        "estimativa_conclusao": 87
    }, {
        "id": "3597",
        "nome": "JOEL ELIAS FADEL FILHO",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "1606.21",
        "dias_trabalhados": "16",
        "proc_30_dias": "197",
        "indice_aceitacao": "90.00",
        "media_produtividade": "12.3",
        "estimativa_conclusao": 61
    }, {
        "id": "3579",
        "nome": "LINCOLN N\u00c9SPOLI DE CAMARGO",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "240.24",
        "dias_trabalhados": "25",
        "proc_30_dias": 0,
        "indice_aceitacao": "66.67",
        "media_produtividade": 0,
        "estimativa_conclusao": 0
    }, {
        "id": "3543",
        "nome": "MARIANA SCHOEMBERGER",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": 0,
        "dias_trabalhados": 0,
        "proc_30_dias": 0,
        "indice_aceitacao": 0,
        "media_produtividade": 0,
        "estimativa_conclusao": 0
    }, {
        "id": "3724",
        "nome": "MICHELLE RIBAS BUMILLER",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": 0,
        "dias_trabalhados": 0,
        "proc_30_dias": 0,
        "indice_aceitacao": 0,
        "media_produtividade": 0,
        "estimativa_conclusao": 0
    }, {
        "id": "143",
        "nome": "OSEIAS GOMES DE MORAES",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false
    }]
}, {
    "nome": "Ponta Grossa - Oficinas",
    "profissionais": [{
        "id": "1455",
        "nome": "ADRIANA RAQUEL LOUREN\u00c7O ALMEIDA MENDON\u00c7A DURAU",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "666.03",
        "dias_trabalhados": "11",
        "proc_30_dias": "61",
        "indice_aceitacao": "92.86",
        "media_produtividade": "5.5",
        "estimativa_conclusao": 90
    }, {
        "id": "210",
        "nome": "AM\u00c9LIA CRISTINE BAHLS",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "0.00",
        "dias_trabalhados": "7",
        "proc_30_dias": 0,
        "indice_aceitacao": "0.00",
        "media_produtividade": 0,
        "estimativa_conclusao": 0
    }, {
        "id": "590",
        "nome": "ANDRESSA SORACE CRONTHAL",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "0.00",
        "dias_trabalhados": "4",
        "proc_30_dias": 0,
        "indice_aceitacao": "0.00",
        "media_produtividade": 0,
        "estimativa_conclusao": 0
    }, {
        "id": "4706",
        "nome": "ANELYSE ANDERES GALVAO",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "300.04",
        "dias_trabalhados": "8",
        "proc_30_dias": "36",
        "indice_aceitacao": "83.33",
        "media_produtividade": "4.5",
        "estimativa_conclusao": 44
    }, {
        "id": "2274",
        "nome": "CAMILA LAIZ BACOVIS",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "730.66",
        "dias_trabalhados": "20",
        "proc_30_dias": "124",
        "indice_aceitacao": "73.33",
        "media_produtividade": "6.2",
        "estimativa_conclusao": 23
    }, {
        "id": "713",
        "nome": "DAIANE LACERDA DANIEL",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "0.00",
        "dias_trabalhados": 0,
        "proc_30_dias": 0,
        "indice_aceitacao": "0.00",
        "media_produtividade": 0,
        "estimativa_conclusao": 0
    }, {
        "id": "1938",
        "nome": "EDUARDO OLIVEIRA DOS SANTOS",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "1392.03",
        "dias_trabalhados": "20",
        "proc_30_dias": "189",
        "indice_aceitacao": "86.36",
        "media_produtividade": "9.5",
        "estimativa_conclusao": 54
    }, {
        "id": "2255",
        "nome": "GIANCARLO DE QUADROS",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "1200.32",
        "dias_trabalhados": "7",
        "proc_30_dias": "11",
        "indice_aceitacao": "66.67",
        "media_produtividade": "1.6",
        "estimativa_conclusao": 49
    }, {
        "id": "2104",
        "nome": "GIOVANNA MENDES STADLER",
        "bloqueio_efetivacao": false,
        "ticket_medio": "1563.54",
        "dias_trabalhados": "11",
        "indice_aceitacao": "66.67",
        "media_produtividade": "1.6",
        "estimativa_conclusao": 49
    }]
}]
```

About the franquiasProfissionais.

1. I pass the request result to the PagerAdapter
2. On the PagerAdapter it is used on the getItem method, which I
   already described

   ```
   BloqueioPager adapter = new BloqueioPager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount(), result);
   ```

Comment: Show us your JSON please and where is `franquiasProfissionais` assigned a value?

Comment: You might need to store `franquiasProfissionais` in the `savedInstanceState`.

Comment: How are you getting `franquiasProfissionais` inside fragment? Please add class where `onItemClick` is defined.

Comment: I add more info to the question

Answer (score 0):

#### What the problem?

Now you have a scenario, which assumes that you have a immediate connection. So what will be in case is not it is? You fill fragment before request is finishe and in this case you send a `null` instance to constructor.

Decouple your fill logic into getting request, parse it, and display. Now you fill fragment data `onActivityCreated`

1) Create a `fill(JSONObject object)` method and `update()` method inside fragment.
2) Put into your Fragment some ProgressView to show to user that the request is processing.
3) When request is success call `fill` method and `update` fragment.
4) Hide progressView

Comment: Actually, when the request is done I pass the result to the PagerAdapter, which pass an specific index position to the Fragment. I though that when I back to the first activity, the request would be called again and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I did something that I think is not correct, but at least it works. I know that everything is loaded correctly when I open the the activity and everything falls apart when I get back to it. So I did this on the second activity:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finish();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BloqueioActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Now it's working but I'm not happy with it. What do you think about this "workaround"?

Answer (score 0):

Try using startActivityForResult instead startActivity. That way your activity will be in tact when you return from second activity.

Comment: I'll take a look into this method.